# Remove duplicates from a json list javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mongodb, duplicates

Good evening,
I have this list from mongoDB that I would like to remove duplicates of countries contain in "title" to insert them in a select box.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60885f86f642f81910ca8715"
    },
    "title": "france",
    "phase": "budget",
    "amount": 45555,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2020,
    "availibleYears": "2020"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60885f86f642f81910ca8716"
    },
    "title": "france",
    "phase": "budget",
    "amount": 7777,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2020,
    "availibleYears": "2020"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60885f86f642f81910ca8717"
    },
    "title": "france",
    "phase": "budget",
    "amount": 8777,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2019,
    "availibleYears": "2019"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60885f86f642f81910ca8719"
    },
    "title": "germany",
    "phase": "budget",
    "amount": 6767,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2020,
    "availibleYears": "2020"
}
```

So far I found this :

```
getUnique(arr, comp){
        const unique = arr
        //store the comparison values in array
        .map(e => e[comp])
        //store the keys of the unique objects
        .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
        //eliminate the dead keys (duplicate) & store unique objects
        .filter(e => arr[e])
        .map(e => arr[e])
        return unique
    }
```

And my select options are :

```
<div className="choose-country">
                    Select {" "}
                    <select>
                       {uniqueCountry.map(country => (
                                <option key={country._id}
                                        value={country.title}>
                                        {country.title}
                                </option>
                       ))}
                    </select>
 </div>
```

I only have one country back with the function getUnique because the code I use is for an array I believe ?
How can I do it ?
Hope it is clear enough and thank you in advance!

Comment: For starters, this appears to be entirely about JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you were asking.
Here is how to select unique elements by title:

```
 getUnique(arr){
   return arr.reduce((accumulator, el) =>{
    if(!accumulator.some(existing => el.title === existing.title)){
      accumulator.push(el); 
    }
    return accumulator;
   },[]);
}
```